# Is there a way to find a point on a circle, given another point and an arc length without using trig functions?

Tags: geometry

Emphasis on not using the trig functions. For example, the problem would be something like find the point $\pi/3$ units counterclockwise from the point $(1,0)$ on the unit circle, without using trig functions. I feel like it must be possible, but I'm drawing a total blank on how it might be done.

Comment: If it were possible, why would anyone *ever* bother with the trig functions?

Comment: You just gave the exact definition of the functions $\cos$ and $\sin$. So what do you accept as primitive operations ?

Comment: My guess is because it is much more complicated to do so? I honestly don't know, but it seems strange that there's no way to derive the values of the sine function using algebra and geometry.

Comment: These are transcendent functions, meaning that they take an infinite number of algebraic operations to be computed. Do you want to know about numerical methods to compute approximations ?

Comment: Using a compass? Other than that, I don't think so as this the basis of trigonometry I'm afraid.

Comment: Good point. I forgot that important fact. So then yes, is there a decent way to compute approximations? I know calculators use the Taylor Series expansion...

Answer (score 0):

For this very specific case we can do: call that point $(x,y)$. As the angle formed by the two radii at (1,0) and  (x,y)  at origin is $\pi/3$, then we see that the chord and these radii form an equilateral triangle. So $(x,y)$ is at distance 1 from the origin as well as $(1,0)$: so we have to find 
a simultaneous  solution to the following two equations: $x^2+y^2=1$ and $(x-1)^2+ y^2=1$.  Hence $x^2 =(x-1)^2 $. So $x=\frac12$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt3}2$.